# PyQt5 / eglfs: Draw call returned Cannot allocate memory. Expect corruption

Tags: python-3, qt

Rather sure this is *not* a PyQt specific question, but that's the context.

When attempting to start a PyQt5 from CLI/text mode into eglfs, I am met with the following errors:

```
QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Unsupported framebuffer format.
QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete, missing attachment.
Draw call returned Cannot allocate memory.  Expect corruption.
Segmentation fault
```

In addition to the usual JIT-not-active warnings.

Same app (mostly) runs in full Windowed mode, though I actually run into similar errors but it does start up.  In CLI mode the app almost starts (you see it render for about one second) then the system returns to CLI with aforementioned errors and locks up.

Does anyone have any guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my case, I was non-optimally using shaders to rescale a bunch of bitmaps, which ended up filling up my memory.  Optimizing that cleared up the problem.

This answer is probably not super-helpful, but at least we can deduce that the segfault appears connected to that and not necessarily some driver bug